# C++ error converting a string to a double

Tags: c++, atof

I am trying to convert a string to a double.  The code is very simple.

```
            double first, second;
            first=atof(str_quan.c_str());
            second=atof(extra[i+1].c_str());
            cout<<first<<" "<<second<<endl;
            quantity=first/second;
```

when trying to convert extra, the compiler throws this gem of wisdom at me:

> error: request for member c_str in
>   extra.std::basic_string<_CharT,
>   _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, _Alloc =
>   std::allocator](((unsigned
>   int)(i + 1))), which is of non-class
>   type char

I have no idea what that means.  if I cout extra[i+1], I get 3.  If I leave extra as a string, the program tries to div first (2) by 51 (ascii for 3).  What the heck is going on?

Comment: My guess is: extra is a string, `extra[i + 1]` is a char, and a char doesn't have a `c_str` method. If you want to convert part of the string, you can probably do something like `atof(extra.c_str()[i + 1])`

Comment: That code is not complete - you're missing the definition of "extra".

Comment: Just tried that.

error: invalid conversion from const char to const char*
error:  initializing argument 1 of double atof(const char*)

Comment: @UncleBens - +1 for the selfless act of putting the correct answer as a comment

Comment: The code is complete, I just did not post all of it.  I can if you think that will help.

Comment: Sorry, make that `atof(extra.c_str() + i + 1)` or you'll need to take the address if you want to index the char array: `atof(&extra.c_str()[i + 1])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like `extra` is a `std::string`, so `extra[i+1]` returns a `char`, which is of non-class type.

It sounds like you are trying to parse the string `extra` starting from the `i+1`th position.  You can do this using:

```
second = atof(extra.substr(i + 1).c_str());
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you.  I have been at this for over an hour.

Comment: Alternativly: `extra.c_str()+(i+1)` which avoids creating a temporary string object

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, `extra` is of type `std::string`. When you do `extra[i+1]`, the result is of type `char` and contains the character in the string `extra`at position `i+1`.

Probably not what you intended.

As a fix, replace `extra[i+1]` with a new string, as follows:

```
extra2 = extra.substr(i+1);
// ...
second=atof(extra2.c_str());
```

A better way to handle this conversion (which is less prone to error) is to use stringstreams:

```
stringstream ss(str_quan);
double first;
ss >> first;
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said, but I think "extra" is of type std::string.  So the expression "extra[i+1] is character "i+1" of "extra", which seems to be '3'.

What are you actually trying to do?

If you just want characters i+1 through to the end of "extra" (and you know how long extra is), you want something like:

```
 second = atof(extra.c_str() + i + 1);
```

Comment: It is preferable to use `substr` for this purpose since it will throw `std::out_of_range` if `i + 1` is past the end of the string.

Comment: At the cost of a temporary; that's why I said "and you know how long extra is".  However, I take your point; an alternative would be "assert(i + 1 < extra.size())" before the call to atof(). As we make this code more idiomatic C++, we'd ditch atof(), and possibly use boost::iterator_range and boost::lexical_cast ...

Answer (score 0):

When asking for help it is often reallyt usfull to provide a compilable example.

My guess (and I emphasis guess becuase there is not enough type information or line numbers).

```
second=atof(extra[i+1].c_str());

// Guess 
// extra is std::string.
```

Thus extra[x] is returning a char which does not have a method c_str()