# C++ parameters of an input stream

Tags: parameters, input, stream

I was just wondering, is there anyway that you can have your user input the location of a file when trying to using a stream?

Ex of what I want to do:

```
int main()
{
ifstream instream; 

string file_location;
cout << "Enter in file location: " << endl; 
cin >> file_location;
instream.open(file_location);
}
```

So I want them to input the file location but the program won't compile.

The error message I'm getting is:

> no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream >::open(std::string&)'

Answer (score 1):

Use `instream.open(file_location.c_str());` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but your types are a little incorrect.  `open` takes a const char*, not a std::string, so you need to provide the const char* that the string contains.  The [`c_str()` method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) of std::string will return the const char* that represents the std::string.

For instance:

```
instream.open(file_location.c_str());
```

Comment: After turning it into a cstring, I still get the error:

request for member 'c_str' in 'file_location', which is of non-class type 'char'

Comment: @kol: So it was, and yours was posted while I was still typing, so I upvoted you.

Comment: @knguyen2525: Something doesn't quite add up.. Are you doing an array index you didn't mention?  See this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694798/c-error-converting-a-string-to-a-double

Comment: I got it to work.  I'm supposed to keep it a type string and convert it into a cstring.  Thanks for all the help guys!